# Reference request: Grothendieck construction for $\mathbb V$-distributors?

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, fibered-categories, grothendieck-construction

I'm currently working with an analogue of the Grothendieck construction for enriched categories:

Given a distributor a.k.a. $\mathbb V$-functor $D:X^\mathrm{op}\otimes Y\to \mathbb V$ there is a structure of a $\mathbb V$-category on the set
$$
\coprod_{X\times Y}\mathbb V(I, D(x,y))=\{\,(x,\phi,y)\,\,|\,\, \phi:I\to D(x,y),x\in X,y\in Y\,\}
$$
with $[(x,\phi,y),(x',\phi',y')]$ given by the pullback of the cospan
$$
[x,x']\to [x,x']\otimes D(x',y') \to D(x,y') \leftarrow D(x,y)\otimes [y,y'] \leftarrow [y,y'].
$$
This construction directly generalises the Grothendieck construction for $\mathrm{Set}$-valued distributors between ordinary categories.

**Question:** What literature does allready exist on this subject?

Comment: I think that isn't possible in general, because this construction become naturally a category and the profunctor D is "splitted by two funtors" (see mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/FIBR/DiWo.pdf §6.4). Now preaddittive categories are one object Ab-enriched one, and Ab-profuntors are bimodules, now I seem that the associated composition functor $(-){}_A\otimes B$ isn't (ever) equivalent to a extension-restriction of rings..

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I had actually read this section a few weeks back but totally forgot about it.

I don't understand your objection, though: Could you explain in a bit more detail why the case you describe is a problem?

Comment: Ab= "commuative groups". A preaddittive category is a  Ab-enriched category (abbr. "p.a.cat"), a rings R, S,.. are  p.a.cat's with olny one object. a Ab-profunctor $M: A\to B$ is a $(A, B)$-bimodule. If Ab-enriched construction exist for ${}_AM_B$ then (as they did in the refernce) you have two rings morphism $f: D\to A$     $g: D\to B$ such that $N\otimes_A M = g_*(f^*(M))=(N_{|D})\otimes_D B$ but I seems the this cannot be true in general

Comment: I assume $D$ is your symbol for the supposed Grothendieck construction. If so: Note that the construction I sketched above yields an Ab-Category having in general more than one object. For example the Grothendieck construction for $M=_AM_B$ yields an Ab-category with object set $M$ and morphism objects $[m,n]=\{(a,b)|am=nb\}$.

Comment: yes right, thinking to rings I close my mind to one-object category (mistake). I seems that work, in Johnstone "TOpos theory" (1978), he do this construction in internal category context, I try to extend this to a monoidal situation, but seems that dont work (need universal property of pullbaks(?)).

Anyway above was $g_*(f^*(N))$

Comment: Hi, I have find this article: 
The Grothendieck Construction and Gradings for Enriched Categories (Tamaki D)
http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0907.0061

Comment: @BuschiSergio: Yep; found this one as well: The difference is that the paper deals with functors $$I\to\mathbb V\mathrm{-Cat}$$
where $I$ is an ordinary category; whereas I consider $\mathbb V$-functors $$X\to\mathbb V$$ where $X$ is a $\mathbb V$-category.

Comment: I have a answere, but (as ever) I'm no too sure, can I Email you ? (I'm sergiobuschi@yahoo.com)